# Direct requests to a specific path based on the subdomain

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, amazon-s3, dns, routes

Assuming I have a static website hosted on S3 and want `http://app.example.com` to serve the contents of `<s3-bucket>/app/index.html`, is that possible?

Comment: yes, I think you can modify the index page settings in your bucket accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Yes, view the S3 bucket in the AWS Console, go to Properties and make sure `Static Website Hosting` is enabled.

Within the settings you have `Index document` that can be configured. By default this is set to `index.html`. Update this to `app/index.html` and then that will be the default page of that bucket.